# How to redirect the std output of a C++ program into a file in VSCode on Mac OS by "launch.json"?

Tags: c++, macos, visual-studio-code, lldb

I'm trying to let the output of a C++ program to go into a file, say, "image.ppm". Actually, using the following `launch.json` file works pretty well on my Ubuntu 20.04.

```json
{
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/raytracing",
        "args": [">image.ppm"],
        "postDebugTask": "open_image_linux",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        // "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
        "preLaunchTask": "Build",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            },
            {
                "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    },
```

When I try to implement a similar procedure on Mac OS, something wried happened, here is my new `launch.json` file:

```json
    {
        "name": "(lldb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/build/raytracing",
        "args": [">image.ppm"],
        "postDebugTask": "open_image_mac",
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "lldb",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        // "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
        "preLaunchTask": "Build",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for lldb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            },
            {
                "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                "text": "-lldb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
```

As can be seen, I just changed the debugger from `gdb` to `lldb` since `gdb` doesn't natively support Apple Silicon right now. However, the `image.ppm` will not be created after the execution of the program, while the output of the program goes into the debug console, like this:

[image]

I think, intrinsically, `"args": [">image.ppm"]`, should work, since it works smoothly on Linux. I guess the reason may be related to the different features of `gdb` and `lldb`. Since when I run the program in VSCode on Ubuntu, nothing will be shown in the debug console. But I don't know how could I solve this problem.

Comment: In order to properly use LLDB with VS Code, you need the LLDB extension.

Comment: But are you trying to debug your program or not? If not, you should figure out another method that isn't hijacking the debugger configuration.

Comment: Thank you @sweenish for your reply. I'm not so sure about some terminologies, but I think I'm not? Because I add the following line in my CMakeLists.txt `set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)`. I just press F5, and the source code is compiled and executed. If I want to use breakpoints or some other debugging features, it won't work.

Is the extension you mentioned this one [lldb-vscode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lanza.lldb-vscode)?

Comment: @sweenish Here is some other information. I modified the BUILD_TYPE flag to be the debug and add a breakpoint. It works pretty well. So I think the problem is why the output of the program doesn't go to the `image.ppm`. Will `LLDB` reset the output of the program to else where?

Comment: If you just want your program to create a file, why don't you make your program do it? From what I can tell, this is a hack. And not the cool, Sneakers type. You're hijacking the debugger configuration to just make your program run and dump its output to a file. C++ code can already do that for you. Or, at a minimum, you should be creating a task instead of abusing the debugger configuration.

Comment: @sweenish, you are correct, I will try it.